# angular-moment-picker appears on the bootstrap model background

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-moment

I am trying to set angular-moment-picker on bootstrap model whenever I click the button to pick up time, the picker appears on the background.

here is my source code:

```
   <div class="form-group" >
                            <p class="icon-group input-group">
                                <input readonly ng-model="startDate" class="form-control" >
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button moment-picker="startDate"
                                    format="HH:mm"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="startDate">
                                <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                            </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: fix the `z-index` property of the datepicker

Comment: @AgamBanga Thank you for anwering this issue, I can't locate the picker how to do it. Thank you

Comment: which version of moment picker are you using?

Comment: @AgamBanga moment-picker#^0.10.1

Comment: check this https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/issues/180

Comment: @AgamBanga z-index will be setted for the button ?

Comment: @khaleed it will be for whole picker div

Comment: @AgamBanga I have setted the z-index to 1070 I get the same problem